# how to change date format in react

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I am new to React and i have been working on this project which requires me to use datepicker.

I am using DateTimePickerModal module in my react native project
and the output of the date i am getting is like this == Fri May 21 2021 13:45:52 GMT+0530 (IST) ==

that ouput datatype is an object.

my required output should be like this == 21/05/2021 1:45 pm ==

can any one please guide me here ?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import DateTimePickerModal from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const Rem = function (props) {
    //const [dateswitch ,setDateSwitch]=useState(true)
    const [isDatePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisibility] = useState(false);
    //button state
    const [b1, setBl] = useState(false);
    const [b2, setB2] = useState(false);
    //date state
    const [b1date, setb1Date] = useState('');
    const [b2date, setb2Date] = useState('');

    //============== showDatePicker ==================

    //get item from storage
    const gettime = async () => {
        try {
            const value1 = await AsyncStorage.getItem('b1');
            if (value1 !== null) {
                // value previously stored
                setb1Date(value1);
            }
            const value2 = await AsyncStorage.getItem('b2');
            if (value2 !== null) {
                // value previously stored
                setb2Date(value2);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // error reading value
        }
    };
    gettime();
    const b1showDatePicker = () => {
        setBl(true);
        setDatePickerVisibility(true);
    };
    const b2showDatePicker = () => {
        setB2(true);
        setDatePickerVisibility(true);
    };

    const hideDatePicker = () => {
        setDatePickerVisibility(false);
    };

    const handleConfirm = async (date) => {
        const d = date.toString()
        if (b1 === true) {
            try {
                //console.warn('A date has been picked: ', d);
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('b1', d);
                setb1Date(d);
                setBl(false);
                hideDatePicker();
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                //console.warn('A date has been picked: ', d);
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('b2', d);
                setb2Date(d);
                setB2(false);
                hideDatePicker();
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    };



    return (
        <View >
            <View style={styles.button_container}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={b1showDatePicker}>
                    <Text style={styles.button}>reminder 1 </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={b2showDatePicker}>
                    <Text style={styles.button}>reminder 2</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{b1date}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{b2date}</Text>
            <DateTimePickerModal
                is24Hour={true}
                isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
                mode="datetime"
                onConfirm={handleConfirm}
                onCancel={hideDatePicker}
            />
        </View>
    );

}

export default Rem;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a function to format Date like this

```
const FormatDate = (data) => {
    let dateTimeString =
      data.getDate() +
      '/' +
      (data.getMonth() + 1) +
      '/' +
      data.getFullYear() +
      ' ';

    let hours = data.getHours();
    let minutes = data.getMinutes();
    let ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12;
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    dateTimeString = dateTimeString + hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;

    return dateTimeString; // 4/5/2021 4:34 pm
  };
```

Then while storing date, do like this

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem('b1', FormatDate(d));
```

or in else condition

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem('b2', FormatDate(d));
```

Here is a [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/date-time-format) to see working example..It will run on iOS and Android only as

`DateTimePicker is not supported on: web`

Comment: @AdityaPrakash Happy to help. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: As @KartikeyVaish said. You must accept answer (By click on the grey check mark next to Kartikey Vaish answer's) It just to mark question as accepted and help new people in Stack Overflow.